# Android adding n text fields

Tags: java, android

I just started learning android programming and can't seem to work out how to permit the user to create a selected number (n) of EditText fields by clicking a button n times such that each would be uniquely identified, namely 1,2,3...,n as well as accessible programatically, from a different method (invoked by a different button click). I hope the question is clear enough as I don't really have that much code to provide.

Comment: Can you post your code anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
// A list to keep reference to your created edit texts
List<EditText> mEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

// Get root view of your activity
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) 
            findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

// Get the button and set a click listener to it
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // Build edit text
        EditText mEditText = new EditText(v.getContext());

        // Pass two args (arg1/arg2); must be LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, or an integer pixel value.
        mEditText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(arg1, arg2));

        // Add the edit text to your list
        mEditTexts.add(mEditText);

        // Add edit text to your root view
        viewGroup.addView(mEditText);
    }
}
```

To check your edit text fields you can then access them from the list

```
for(EditText editText : mEditTexts){
    Log.d(TAG, editText.getEditableText().toString());
}
```

or explicitly

```
int specificPosition = (SOME_INT);
EditText specificEditText = mEditTexts.get(specificPosition);
```

Haven't been able to test it so it might need some modifying but it should be something along those lines. You can also use your layout directly if you don't want to use the viewGroup. Modify it to something like

```
LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
....
mLayout.addView(mEditText);
```

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai you can set them to an array or something. Check edits. Just one of the ways to do it